# Bootstrap 5 card-img-overlay extends into next div container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, cs50

I am designing a painting website for my CS50 homepage and the
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); is not fitting correctly with images in the card-group.

```
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
      <img src="pics/painterpic.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Exterior Cover"/>
  </div>
 <div class="card">
      <img src="pics/cover.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Interior Cover"/>
 </div>
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h1 class="card-title" id="hero-text">Interior Painting Specialists</h1>
      </div>
</div>

CSS:
card-img-overlay {   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7) }
card-img-top   { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

I have tried using <div class="container-fluid> or just container I have tried
.card-img-overlay { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7) position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 1.25rem; border-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px); }

And many other variations. adding width: 100%; height;}

I do not understand why the img-overlay extends past the div that it is included in. It always goes 3 or 4 inches past.

If anyone has any ideas, that would be appreciated. Thx

This is all of the CSS:

```
.box300     {
width:100%;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #999;
background:#fff;
        }

 #hero-text
        {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 56px;
        }

#p-1
        {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 62.5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
        }

.card-img-top
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
.card-img-overlay
        {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

Comment: have you tried `overflow: hidden` on your cards? We would be able to help you better if you would show us the complete css for it

Comment: I have attached all of my programs CSS above.  As you can see I tried inserting the overflow: hidden to the card-img-overlay however it did not change anything.  The issue lies within the card-group as the card-img-overlay works when I use it in a div container with one image.  The card-body seems to extend well past the div container it resides in when I use card-group.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not really sure about what you want to do. You have a card group. Inside this this card group you have two cards and one card-img-overlay. What are you trying to do? Do you have some kind of mockup or image that you can show us?

Comment: I am attempting to create a cover image with two images and specific writing within it.  In order for the writing to stand out I need to use the card-img-overlay {   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7) ; however the transparent background is extending past the image.  If you go to https://certapro.com/landing-page/bing-ppc/?vendor=gso_caputo_design&source=Bing&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Bing+-+Residential&msclkid=a8399533958e128a31e7f657fb241a4c  you can see something similar to what I want although it is ok if the transparent overlay covers the whole image.

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed in the comments, here is an example of what i think you are looking for:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.card-group__image {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card-group__title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 65%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-group">
  <img class="card-group__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/807598/pexels-photo-807598.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" class="card-img-top" alt="Exterior Cover" />
  <img class="card-group__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/793012/pexels-photo-793012.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1600" class="card-img-top" alt="Interior Cover" />
  <h1 class="card-group__title" id="hero-text">Interior Painting Specialists</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  The images are aligned correctly, and the transparent background is perfect for adding any text that is visible.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherWhite Happy to help you. Maybe you could accept the answer as correct so other people in the future can see what worked out for this problem. 

Comment: Yes @Boguz, I did that; but, my reputation isn't high enough for stack exchange to show it in the count.  I think I need 15; but, I only have 11.  Any ideas about how I could improve that?

Comment: @ChristopherWhite The best way is to help someone else.  

Comment: Hi @Boguz.  I am having some trouble getting the images to display correctly on a phone.  I have tried using auto, img-fluid img-responsive, changing the grid and many other methods to get the two pictures to separate on a small screen i.e one on top of the other while having both images side by side on a computer screen.; but I can't seem to get the images to do that with any of the bootstrap attributes or in the CSS.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have also tried row column, column; however, then the img-overlay does n't fit correctly.   Thx again.

Comment: @ChristopherWhite without seeing your code it is difficult to know what the problem is. You probably have some bootstrap styles overing the styles you want. Do you have the site online somewhere where i can see it and debug it?

Comment: @ Boguz I ended up using a Bootstrap Carousel which is now working.  That said, I am new to coding and looking for someone that could aid me in the learning process.  Willing to pay for your time.  Let me know if that is something that interests you.  Thx.

Comment: @ChristopherWhite That sounds great. Let me know how i can contact you...

Comment: @ Boguz.  Great. Contact me at christopherwhitecw1@gmail.com.  Thx